# PowerBI version March 2023. Connect to Azure data lake gen 2 for parquet files error?

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-data-lake-gen2, powerbi-datasource

I have updated powerbi desktop to March 2023 and tried to refresh my data. My data is stored as parquet files in the azure data lake gen 2. Upon refreshing I receive an error

*Could not load file or assembly 'ParquetSharp. Version = 0.0.0.0, Cultre = neutral. PublicKeyToken =.... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I have another vm where my powerbi desktop version is Sept 2022 and tried refreshing and it worked fine.

Why is this error occuring? and Is there a way I can get around/ solve? I've seen people mention that the parquet connector is broken in the March 2023 version of powerbi desktop, is this true?

Comment: Check the [link-PBI community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Parquet-connector-error-after-November22-Update/td-p/2941874). Try **Uninstalling** and **reinstalling** the Power BI desktop.